# Rings and sequences

Tags: sequences

I find it surprising that rings (from `make-ring`) are sequences (satisfy `sequencep`), but cannot be operated on by standard sequence functions (`length`, `elt`, etc.).

What, then, does being a "sequence" entail? The [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequences-Arrays-Vectors.html#Sequences-Arrays-Vectors) says that:

> The “sequence” type is the union of two other Lisp types: lists and
>   arrays.  In other words, any list is a sequence, and any array is a
>   sequence.  The common property that all sequences have is that each is
>   an ordered collection of elements.

The diagram in the manual does not include rings. Should rings really be considered sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Predicate `sequencep` returns non-nil if its argument is a list or an array, and in this case "list" includes a cons cell (a dotted pair).  `(sequencep '(a . b))` returns `t`.

```
(setq foo  (make-ring 3))
```

`C-h v foo` shows that `foo` is `(0 0 . [nil nil nil])`.

So a ring is a sequence - because it is a cons, but a sequence is not necessarily a ring.

Whether `sequencep` should behave this way in Emacs Lisp is a good question.  It does not correspond to what Common Lisp considers a sequence, for instance.  In Common Lisp only proper lists (with `nil` as the last cdr) are sequences, not dotted lists.

You have function `ring-convert-sequence-to-ring`, which returns a ring that corresponds to its sequence argument.